# Find all vectors $(x,y,z)$ whose value under the rotation..

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, rotations

Find all vectors $(x,y,z)$ whose value under the rotation through the angle $\pi/2$ about the $y$-axis is the vector $(z,x,y)$

Can anyone please provide some help in answering this question

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If you rotate $(x,y,z)$ around the $y$-axis by an angle equal to $\frac\pi2$, you will get $(-z,y,x)$. So, solve the equation $(-z,y,x)=(z,x,y)$.

Comment: When I fill $\pi$/2 into the rotation matrix about the y axis and multiply by (x,y,z) I get (z,y,-x). What should I do when I let (z,y,-x) = (z,x,y)? Thanks for your help

Comment: The matrix, with respect to the canonical basis, of a rotation of angle $\theta$ around the $y$-axis is$$\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&0&-\sin\theta\\0&1&0\\\sin\theta&0&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}.$$So, if $\theta=\frac\pi2$, that matrix is$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&-1\\0&1&0\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$and$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&-1\\0&1&0\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-z\\y\\x\end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Rotation metrix is,$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    -1 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$

So required condition is$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    -1 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$ 
$\begin{pmatrix}
    x \\
    y \\
    z \\
    \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
    z \\
    x \\
    y \\
    \end{pmatrix}$

This gives, $z=z,y=x,-x=y$

$\therefore x=y=0$.

so any vector of the form $(0,0,z)$ satisfies the required condition.